# Kendo Grid Sort Broken with Custom Editor

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, custom-controls

My example demonstrates that the official kendo demo with a custom inline editor cannot be sorted by the custom editor column (Category): http://dojo.telerik.com/agoBi/2

This is the original kendo example (without sorting enabled):

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

...to it, I added following code to be able to sort the grid (see my example at top):

```
sortable: true
```

The statement above is officially supported by Kendo and works on any other (normal) columns.

Does anyone know how to add this functionality whilst retaining the custom editor column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does because grid does not know work with nested objects. If you want allow sorting for nested objects, you have to bind column to that nested object. Here [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/agoBi/4)
Especially change is in columns object on row with categories:

```
{ field: "Category.CategoryName", ...
```

This small modification will allow sorting, but it brings up small issue with the dropdown editor. If you select something in that editor, value will be displayed, but commonly, we are interested in values. Anyway it can be also avoided by small modification in editor, like in this [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/agoBi/5) - especially removed data-bind prop so you have to modify record manually.

Comment: Hi. I have tried your example before. The Problem with it is that when you click on the custom column to change the value, the select box stays empty initially and that is "un-clean"

Comment: And also when I select a value the display changed to a number and not the corresponding value which is not usable

Comment: ad1) it is because autoBind is set to false. Dropdown will not be initialized until you open it. If you set autoBind to true, you will have selected value from the begining. Anyway by default the first value is selected, so if you want select value which is in cell, you need to load that value from model. - Check this [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/agoBi/8)

Comment: ad2) to this question I am not sure that I understand correctly, but if values are not correct - are you selecting value or index?

Comment: ad2) In your posted example (http://dojo.telerik.com/agoBi/4) when you change the category it is not mapped to a string but remains an ID (number). This is what I meant. Problem solved with autobind: true. Thanks

Comment: @Ademar : If i change editable to 

editable:{mode:"popup"}, 

this doesn't work. I get the console error as "Cannot read property 'set' of null". Because 

$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(this.element.closest("tr")) 

is null. Any solution for popup editing scenarios...?

Comment: @PABODHAWIMALASURIYA I just tried change the mode to popup in dojo example above and it worked without a problem. Is it possible to create a dojo example of your current problem? http://dojo.telerik.com/iZAJEzOG

Comment: @Ademar : http://dojo.telerik.com/iZAJEzOG/2 i think u missed to add change func. and i noticed one more thing. Before i click UPDATE, popup getting closed (soon after i type a text on name field or when select a item from drop down). By the way, still the above mentioned error is there..

Comment: @Ademar : We are in a quick hot fixes round. so for now i added a fix using the custom sorting comparer just for the Category column. Something like 
~~~
return x.Category.CategoryName === y.Category.CategoryName ? 0 : (x.Category.CategoryName > y.Category.CategoryName) ? 1 : -1;
~~~ 
Support link : https://onabai.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/kendoui-grid-custom-sorting-algorithms/
.If you found a permanant solution, please let me know. Thank you..

Comment: @PABODHAWIMALASURIYA Problem with $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(this.element.closest("tr")) is null is because this.element.closest("tr") returns nothing (you can test by console.log(this.element.closest("tr")). But you don't need change event at all. You need change column bound to object field (not to property inside object) so instead of Category.CategoryName, you use just Category. Because of template it will still display correct value and dropdown knows what field it is bound to. 
Problem with autoclosing, when you select value is because there is autoSync: true. You can remove

Comment: it (default value is false) -> reference: https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-(custom)-popup-closing(updates-happening)-after-input-select-change
And working dojo example: http://dojo.telerik.com/iZAJEzOG/3

Comment: @Ademar I checked your dojo example. Yes, it's all good. But one thing. Sorting doesn't work for Category column in that case..

Comment: Ah ye, you are right. I forgot about original question after those years. Anyway, I don't see another possibility, than not use "options.field" in binding dropdownlist to the model, but write name of your property you want to bind by yourself. Here is a dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/iZAJEzOG/4

Comment: @Ademar : Thank you for the answers and all the help examples. Yes i will follow this. It works as expected.